# using JsonPath to filter json message

Tags: json, filter, jsonpath

I have json message:

```
{
  "a1":"1",
  "a2":"2",
  "a3":"3"
}
```

The requirement is only accept message with a2==2, ignore others.

I am trying to use jsonpath to return message only when "a2"==2.

Can you help me.

Comment: `I am trying`. Show what you've done so far

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko. Here is what i tried but not successful: $(?(@.a2=="2"))

Comment: You need to filter out proper JSON objects from array or to test if given single object is proper? Please provide more details, maybe even [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

the common way is

```
var result =jsonObject.a2;
```

but if you like it a hard way

```
var result = jsonPath(jsonObject, "$.a2");
```

Comment: thanks, what if in json message a2=3.

Comment: @David , it doesnt matter what type, javascript doesn't check it. it will be working the same way.